# How to have Ctrl+[key] modify a full word and Alt+[key] modify a partial word in ZSH?

Tags: bash, keyboard, shell, zsh

I'm in the process of switching to ZSH as my primary shell and am missing one small configuration option I had in Bash.

I have bash set up so that if I use `Ctrl+Left/Right/Backspace/Delete`, it will move or delete a full word, and if I use `Alt+Left/Right/Backspace/Delete`, it will move or delete a partial word.

By a full word, I mean that pressing `Ctrl+RightArrow` on `aaa/bbb/ccc` would move the cursor from the start to the end of the string (i.e. whitespace separates). By a partial word, I mean that pressing `Alt+RightArrow` on the same string would only move the cursor to just before the first `/` (any non-alphanumeric character separates). A similar principle is applied to the other similar keys.

The issue I have run into is that I can't find commands to assign using `bindkey` that distinguish between these different kinds of input modifications.

How can I achieve this kind of functionality in my ZSH configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zsh unfortunately does not ship with widgets that do exactly that and it’s non-trivial to write your own. However, you can get ready-made versions of these as part of my [Zsh Edit plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit).